# Makefile - multiple recipes calling one, with variables - only the first gets run

Tags: makefile

I have set up my makefile like below, to minimize code duplication

The recipes are a set of blocks that set a variable, and then run the sleeper_agent recipe. They work great when called individually as `make xlsx_sleeper` for example.

But when I call `all_sleepers`, only the first one (xlsx_sleeper) gets compiled.

I have tried declaring them as phony (`.PHONY: all_sleepers xlsx_sleeper docx_sleeper pptx_sleeper pdf_sleeper png_sleeper`), which changes nothing

and adding a .FORCE rule to the sleeper_agent rule, which results in no such file or directory:

```
.FORCE:
sleeper_agent: .FORCE [...]
```

Here is my makefile:

```
all_sleepers: xlsx_sleeper docx_sleeper pptx_sleeper png_sleeper pdf_sleeper

sleeper_agent: $(OBJ)/sleeper_agent.o $(OBJ)/identities.o
    windres icons/$(ext)/resource.rc -O coff -o obj/$(ext).res
    $(CC) -o $(BIN)/sleeper_$(ext).exe $^ $(OBJ)/$(ext).res $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

xlsx_sleeper: ext=xlsx
xlsx_sleeper: sleeper_agent

docx_sleeper: ext=docx
docx_sleeper: sleeper_agent

pptx_sleeper: ext=pptx
pptx_sleeper: sleeper_agent

png_sleeper: ext=png
png_sleeper: sleeper_agent

pdf_sleeper: ext=pdf
pdf_sleeper: sleeper_agent
```

Comment: Your mental model of `make` is wrong: only the lines in a recipe itself are imperative in nature (plus also the flow of variable definitions with some caveats). The basic execution structure, that is, the determination of which recipe to execute when, is not imperative but a graph flow model: targets are the nodes and the prerequisites define the edges in this graph to the next (earlier) node. A node is updated at most once in a make run, namely when its earlier nodes are younger than itself. Nodes are "global" in this graph, once visited, a node is not considered again in the same run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that make does not see any reason why it should rebuild the `sleeper_agent` target several times. You should probably stick to the make philosophy:

1. Try to have real files as targets (`$(BIN)/sleeper_xlsx.exe`).
2. Use [phony](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) (non-file) targets only:

   - To give symbolic names to other targets or groups of targets (`all_sleepers`, `xlsx_sleeper`, ...)
   - For rules that don't produce files (`clean`, `help`...)
3. Declare phony targets as such (`.PHONY: ...`)

Example using [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern), [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) and the [`patsubst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-patsubst-1) make function:

```
SLEEPER  := xlsx docx pptx png pdf
EXE      := $(patsubst %,$(BIN)/sleeper_%.exe,$(SLEEPER))
SHORT    := $(patsubst %,%_sleeper,$(SLEEPER))

.PHONY: all_sleepers $(SHORT) clean_sleepers

all_sleepers: $(EXE)

$(SHORT): %_sleeper: $(BIN)/sleeper_%.exe

$(EXE): $(BIN)/sleeper_%.exe: $(OBJ)/sleeper_agent.o $(OBJ)/identities.o
    windres icons/$*/resource.rc -O coff -o obj/$*.res
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(OBJ)/$*.res $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

clean_sleepers:
    rm -f $(EXE)
```

And then you should be able to run:

```
make all_sleepers
```

to build them all or:

```
make xlsx_sleeper
```

to build only one of them. `EXE` is the list of real executable files and a static pattern rule explains how to build them. In its recipe the `$*` automatic variable expands as the string matching the `%` wildcard. `SHORT` is the list of `xxxx_sleeper` shortcuts and another static pattern rule explains for each of them to which real executable it corresponds. `all_sleepers` and the `xxxx_sleeper` shortcuts (plus the `clean_sleepers` I added as example) are properly declared as phony because there are no such real files.